# SimpleDateFormat - Strange IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, illegalargumentexception

I've got problem with SimpleDateFormat. I'm given string with date like this:

```
"2013-05-17 10:15:44"
```

And try to parse it with this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(s2);
```

But the last line throws me an IllegalArgumentException. What is wrong with it? It just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(s2); // What is s2?

Comment: Posting complete code helps most of the time.

Comment: looking for this output Format :   Fri May 17 15:45:44 IST 2013?. use this  String date ="2013-05-17 10:15:44";
       
       SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     originalFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      System.out.println("Format :   " + originalFormat.parse(date));

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy - s2 is the string mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how a DateFormat works: it is used to switch between Strings and Dates. So you have two basic operations:

```
Date date = format.parse(someString); //from String to date
String str = format.format(date); //from date to String
```

In your case, I suspect you wanted to do:

```
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s2);
```